# zoom-in & zoom-out is not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have 2 buttons (zoom-in & zoom-out), on zoom-in button click the `#Page` div should zoom in and on zoom-out button click the `#Page` div should zoom out.
For this I have written following javascript,

for zoom out button

```
$("#zoomout").click(
    function(e){
        $("#Page").css( "zoom", "1" );
        $("#Page").css( "-o-transform", "scale(1,1)" );
        $("#Page").css( "-moz-transform", "scale(1,1)" );
        $("#Page").css( "-webkit-transform", "scale(1)" );
        e.preventDefault();     
});
```

for zoom in button

```
$("#zoomin").click(
    function(e){        
        $("#Page").css( "zoom", "2.4" );
        $("#Page").css( "-o-transform", "scale(2.4,2.4)" );
        $("#Page").css( "-moz-transform", "scale(2.4,2.4)" );
        $("#Page").css( "-webkit-transform", "scale(2.4)" );
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

This script working fine on Mozilla Firefox browser,
but not working on Google Chrome browser. How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Try to add a `transform` rule without the vendor prefix.

Comment: Irrelevant to your problem at hand, why are you executing a jQuery selector once for each line? Just pass the values into `.css()` all at once as a hash, or chain the `.css()` calls together. No need to have jQuery look up `#page` every time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
$.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()); 

$("#zoomout").click(
    function(e){
            if($.browser.chrome)
            {
                $("#Page").css("-webkit-transform-origin","0 0");
                $("#Page").css("-webkit-transform","scale(1)");
                $(".Page").css( "background-size", "contain" );
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                    $("#Page").css( "zoom", "1" );
                    $("#Page").css( "-o-transform", "scale(1,1)" );
                    $("#Page").css( "-moz-transform", "scale(1,1)" );
                    $("#Page").css( "-webkit-transform", "scale(1)" );
                    e.preventDefault();
            }
    });


$("#zoomin").click(
    function(e){
            if($.browser.chrome)
            {
                $("#Page").css("-webkit-transform-origin","0 0");
                $("#Page").css("-webkit-transform","scale(2.4)");
                $(".Page").css( "background-size", "100%" );
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else
            {

                    $("#Page").css( "zoom", "2.4" );
                    $("#Page").css( "-o-transform", "scale(2.4,2.4)" );
                    $("#Page").css( "-moz-transform", "scale(2.4,2.4)" );
                    $("#Page").css( "-webkit-transform", "scale(2.4)" );
                    e.preventDefault();
            }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `-webkit-transform` value does not match the other two transforms; it says `scale(1)` instead of `scale(1,1)`.

Try using these lines:

```
$("#Page").css( "-webkit-transform", "scale(1,1)" );

$("#Page").css( "-webkit-transform", "scale(2.4,2.4)" );
```